# Show One Row of Same Customer But Multiple Rows For Unique Orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table customers and orders:

| custid | Cust Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ravi Devgam |
| 2 | Abby Brown |

| orderid | custid | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Phone |
| 2 | 1 | Tablet |
| 3 | 2 | Apple TV |
| 4 | 2 | Laptop |

And I want output in this format:

| Cust Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Ravi Devgam | Phone |
|  | Tablet |
| Abby Brown | Apple TV |
|  | Laptop |

I am getting this result by simple join query:

```
SELECT customers.[Cust name], orders.Item
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.custid = orders.custid
```

| Cust Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Ravi Devgam | Phone |
| Ravi Devgam | Tablet |
| Abby Brown | Apple TV |
| Abby Brown | Laptop |

Comment: I highly recommend using table aliases

Comment: The formatting you are asking for is usually done in your presentation layer - why do you wish to do it in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH ordersAndCustomers AS (

    SELECT
        c.CustName,
        LAG( CustName, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY CustName ) AS CustNameLag1,
        o.Item,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CusName, Item ) AS rn
    FROM
        dbo.Orders AS o
        INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c ON o.CustId = c.CustId
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CustName = CustNameLag1 THEN '' ELSE CustName END AS CustName,
    Item
FROM
    ordersAndCustomers
ORDER BY
    rn
```

---

SQLFiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d010d7/3

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

data

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
   custid    INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Cust_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO customers 
(custid,Cust_Name) VALUES
(1,'Ravi Devgam'),
(2,'Abby Brown');

CREATE TABLE orders(
   orderid INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,custid  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Item    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO orders
(orderid,custid,Item) VALUES 
(1,1,'Phone'),
(2,1,'Tablet'),
(3,2,'Apple TV'),
(4,2,'Laptop');
```

use `Subquery`,`Row_number`,`FULL JOIN` and `IIF` as follows

```
SELECT IIF(cust_name is null,'',cust_name)  cust_name,
       item
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY custid
                   ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) rn
        FROM   orders) a
       FULL JOIN customers c
              ON c.custid = IIF(rn = 1, a.custid, NULL)
ORDER  BY orderid
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-AmFChJA)

Answer (score 0):

You only need ROW_NUMBER();

```
  WITH CustomerOrders
    AS (
SELECT CustomerName = c.[Cust name]
     , o.Item
     , rn = ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY c.[Cust name] ORDER BY o.Item)
  FROM customers          c
  LEFT JOIN orders        o ON c.custid = o.custid
       )
SELECT CustomerName = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN co.CustomerName ELSE '' END
     , ItemName     = COALESCE(co.Item, '')
  FROM CustomerOrders    co;
```

I would also recommend that you get in the habit of schema qualifying your objects - it should be dbo.Customers and dbo.Orders.